# Combine multiple Subjects and Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
  readonly todos$: Observable<Todo[]> = combineLatest([this.account$, this.loadTodoPage$]).pipe(
    concatMap(([account, pageNo]) => this.todoService.getTodos(account.id, pageNo)),
    scan((acc: Todo[], curr: Todo[]) => [...acc, ...curr], [])
  );
```

This always loads a new page of todos from the backend when i emit a new value in the loadTodoPage subject.

Now I need to integrate a third subject in this logic which is responsible for discarding or reopen the todo. The Subject should like like this:
 `readonly modifyTodo$: Subject<{ action: 'discard' | 'reopen'; todo: Todo }> = new Subject();`

When I integrate the subject after the scan operator, the scan will always override the modifications and if I integrate the the subject within the combineLatest it will always also fetch new todos from the backend which is not what I want.

Can someone give me an hint how I can solve this in a declarative approach?

Comment: I don't understand why modifyTodo$ should be linked with the todos$. You would have a button or something to trigger the modifyTodo$, and on the pipe/subscribe, open or close the todo. Why should this subject aware of all the todo$ ?

Comment: I need to link the modifyTodo$ subject with the todos because I want to modify the todos$ array whenever the modifyTodo$ subject emits.
When the modifyTodo$ emits `discard`, I want to remove the given todo from the array and if I `reopen` I want to add it again

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand well, you have

- `fetchedTodos$` for the call to the backend

  ```
  const fetchedTodos$ = combineLatest([this.account$, this.loadTodoPage$]).pipe(
       concatMap(([account, pageNo]) => this.todoService.getTodos(account.id, pageNo)),
       scan((acc: Todo[], curr: Todo[]) => [...acc, ...curr], [])
  );
  ```
- And `modifyTodo$` with new todos.

Then you can combine them together with a combineLatest as you have done it for the `fetchedTodos$`:

```
const todos$ = combineLatest([fetchedTodos$,modifyTodo$]).pipe(
   map(([fetchedTodos,modifiedTodos])=> { ... })
)
```

Comment: The thing is that modifyTodo has only one Todo in memory so as soon as you would trigger two times modifyTodo, and refetch all the todos, there would be a problem. The architecture is imo weird. I think that we should have a modifyTodo which will trigger discard/open and a modifiedTodos wich hold all the previous modified todos.

Comment: I agree that the structure is pretty weird indeed and we can face issues quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could merge `modifyTodo$` into the chain and then let `scan()` handle the logic that updates todos:

```
type Command = { action: 'discard' | 'reopen'; todo: Todo };

readonly todos$: Observable<Todo[]> = combineLatest([this.account$, this.loadTodoPage$]).pipe(
    concatMap(([account, pageNo]) => this.todoService.getTodos(account.id, pageNo)),
    mergeWith(modifyTodo$),
    scan((acc: Todo[], curr: Todo[] | Command) => {
        if (Array.isArray(curr)) {
            return [...acc, ...curr];
        }

        // Update todo
        const todo = acc.find(curr.todo.id);
        if (curr.action === 'discard') {
            todo.whatever = ...;
        } else {
            // ...
        } 
        
        return [...acc];
    }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your list of todo items as accumulation of `TodoActions` if you treat "load" as an action in addition to `reopen` and `discard`:

```js
  private todos$ = this.todoActions$.pipe(
    scan((todos, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'load':
          return todos.concat(action.todos);
        case 'discard': 
          return todos.filter(t => t.id !== action.todo.id)
        case 'reopen':
          return todos.map(t => t.id === action.todo.id ? { ...t, isComplete: false } : t)
      }
    }, [] as Todo[]),
  );
```

With the above code, `todos$` will only emit when an action is received, so we need to emit a `load` action:

```js
this.todoService.getTodos(account.id, pageNum).pipe(
  tap(todos => this.todoActions$.next({ type: 'load', todos }))
)
```

Since our template needs the `nextPage` value, we declare a `nextPage$` observable and have it emit this value:

```js
  private nextPage$ = combineLatest(this.account$, this.pageNum$).pipe(
    mergeMap(([account, pageNum]) => this.todoService.getTodos(account.id, pageNum).pipe(
      tap(todos => this.todoActions$.next({ type: 'load', todos })),
      map(() => pageNum + 1)
    )),
  );
```

Here we call the service, emit the `load` action, then return the next page number.

Finally, we can expose a single view model observable for our template:

```js
  vm$ = combineLatest({
    todos    : this.todos$, 
    nextPage : this.nextPage$
  });
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">

  <h1> Todos </h1>

  <li *ngFor="let todo of vm.todos" > 
    {{ todo.name }} <button (click)="discard(todo)"> x </button>
  </li>

  <button (click)="loadPage(vm.nextPage)"> 
    Load More
  </button>

</ng-container>
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76311832?file=src%2Fmain.html,src%2Fmain.ts) you can play with.